# How do I add left and right classes to every other element in a loop in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I am working within a Ruby on Rails app. I have a loop that creates divs like this:

```
<% @snorks.each do |snork| -%>
  <div>
    <%= snork %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I need the output to have every other div be floated left or right like this:

```
<div class="left">
  Allstar Seaworthy
</div>
<div class="right">
  Casey Kelp
</div>
<div class="left">
  Dimmy Finster
</div>
<div class="right">
  Daffney Gillfin
</div>
<div class="left">
  Tooter Shellby
</div>
<div class="right">
  Dr. / Uncle Galeo
</div>
```

Additionally, I need to add a div with `class="clear"` every two divs, like this:

```
<div class="left">
  Allstar Seaworthy
</div>
<div class="right">
  Casey Kelp
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="left">
  Dimmy Finster
</div>
<div class="right">
  Daffney Gillfin
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="left">
  Tooter Shellby
</div>
<div class="right">
  Dr. / Uncle Galeo
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I have researched, and found a [few](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/84918) [posts](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/15-alternate-row-classes-with-ruby-on-rails) saying that the alternate classes can be accomplished easily by using `cycle()`, and that does work. However, when I use it in two places within the loop it stops working right and just outputs something like this:

```
<div class="left">
  Allstar Seaworthy
</div>
<div class="left">
  Casey Kelp
</div>
<div class="left">
  Dimmy Finster
</div>
<div class="left">
  Daffney Gillfin
</div>
<div class="left">
  Tooter Shellby
</div>
<div class="left">
  Dr. / Uncle Galeo
</div>
```

**What's the best practices way in Ruby on Rails to alternate classes in a loop, and also add something every other loop?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle), if you need nested ones you name them. Otherwise they will both share the name "default" and conflict.

```
<% @snorks.each do |snork| -%>
  <div class="<%= cycle('left', 'right') -%>">
    <%= snork %>
  </div>
  <%= cycle('','<div  class="clear"></div>', :name=>"cleardiv") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

use cycle helper

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle

```
<% @snorks.each do |snork| -%>
  <div  class="<%= cycle("left", "right") -%>">
    <%= snork %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Edit:** for adding new div; following could help

```
<% @snorks.each_slice(2) do |snork_batch| -%>
 <% snork_batch.each do |snork|%>
  <div  class="<%= cycle("left", "right",:name=>"className") -%>">
    <%= snork %>
  </div>
<%end%>
<div  class="clear"></div>
  <% reset_cycle("className")%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried the cycle helper, and it works well for outputting left and right. When I try to use it again in the same loop to add a clear fix div every other loop, neither use of cycle works.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing here seems to be using each with index.  That way you could do some simple modulus math to determine if the number is odd or even and output the correct class and add the clears.

```
@snorks.each_with_index do | snork, index|
   If index%2 == 0 
      class = 'left'
   else
      class = 'right'
   end
```

Well u get my drift and I'm on my phone.