# Rails - how can I display left and right layout for image and its content in every other row

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to to loop through each post and display a left and right layout of image and its content in every other row

like this  [Theme](http://rstheme.com/products/html/khadok/khadok-demo/blog.html)
basically the html is:

```
<div class="container">

    <div>
    <div class="images"><img src="image1"></div>
    <div class="images-content">content 1 here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="images images-right"><img src="image2"></div>
    <div class="images-content images-content-right">content 2 here</div>
    </div>

   <div>
    <div class="images"><img src="image3"></div>
    <div class="images-content">content 3 here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="images images-right"><img src="image4"></div>
    <div class="images-content images-content-right">content 4 here</div>
    </div>

   <div>
    <div class="images"><img src="image5"></div>
    <div class="images-content">content 5 here</div>
    </div>

    <div>
    <div class="images images-right"><img src="image6"></div>
    <div class="images-content images-content-right">content 6 here</div>
    </div>


 </div>
```

I have tried this [cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474636/how-do-i-add-left-and-right-classes-to-every-other-element-in-a-loop-in-ruby-on) example

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

  <div class="<%= cycle('images', 'images images-right') %>">
    Image here
  </div>

<% end %>
```

but the problem is how to add the respective content div classes which goes with the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to add classes dynamically to your odd-indexed posts.

Also, please prefer using [image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) instead of using raw HTML to create `<img>` tag.

```
<div class="container">
  <% @posts.each.with_index do |post, index| %>
    <div class="images <%= 'images-right' if index.odd? %>"><%= image_tag post.image %></div>
    <div class="images-content <%= 'images-content-right' if index.odd? %>"><%= post.content %></div>
  <% end %>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It on what attributes your Post model has. Presumably it has `content` and `image` attributes?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <div class="<%= cycle('images', 'images images-right') %>">
      <%= post.image %>
    </div>
    <div class="<%= cycle('images-content', 'images-content images-content-right') %>">
      <%= post.content %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes Post model has content and image attributes. thanks - I have tried above answer earlier but it didn't work. I want "image left content right, next row content left image right..." in order like [this](http://rstheme.com/products/html/khadok/khadok-demo/blog.html)